# Add Value with Custom Parameters into WCF Header

Tags: c#, wcf, soapheader

**Hi we are using some goverment WCF service.
In old method they are looking in soap header like this.**

```
<islemKodu>2</islemKodu>
<islemNedeni>Döküman iptal edildi</islemNedeni>
```

**and we are add in MessageInspector to this;**

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("islemKodu", "", "2"));
request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("islemNedeni", "", "Döküman iptal edildi"));
return null;
}
```

**so this is working right.**

**but goverment has change the soap header like this.**

```
<param:SaglikNetParameters xmlns:param="http://saglik-net.saglik.gov.tr/parametreler/">
<param:parameter name="islemKodu">2</param:parameter>
<param:parameter name="islemNedeni">Döküman iptal edildi</param:parameter>
</param:SaglikNetParameters>
```

so now how can i change our BeforeSendRequest method to send like this custom parameters in soap header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a special header class to output the soap XML to match the required structure. Look at this [blog post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/internal-classes-to-understand-wcf-message-xmldictionarywriter-class/) for the code you need to implement.

Basically, you need to create the class to output the required XML and then use that class as follows:

```
// %< snipped >%

var specialHeader = GovMsgHeader.CreateHeader( /* any parameters */ );
request.Headers.Add(specialHeader);

// %< snipped >%
```

The special class would look something like this:

```
public class GovMsgHeader : MessageHeader {
    protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(
        System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer,
        MessageVersion messageVersion) {

        base.OnWriteStartHeader(writer, messageVersion);

        // Write your custom XML using the XmlDictionaryClass:
        //TODO: add the 'param' XML namespace to the writer...
        //TODO: add the container element with something like this:
        writer.WriteElementString("SaglikNetParameters", "param", "");

        writer.WriteElementString("parameter", "param", "2");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "", "islemKodu");
        //TODO: complete the rest of the XML ...
    }
}
```

Comment: writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "", "islemKodu"); thats the point for me ! thank you.